# Iterate through an array in a collection and display in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've got a template for a todo with a list for comments. Each todo has an array "comments" of comments in localstorage. I fetch all todos, iterate through each todo's "comments" array and I want all comments to be assigned to the corresponding todo. How do I append to the right comment-list?

Currently I get the output like this one:

```
Post1
  Comment1_Post1
  Comment2_Post1
  Comment1_Post2
  Comment2_Post2
Post2
  Comment1_Post2
  Comment2_Post2
```

Edit1: the new CommentCollectionView

```
 render: function() {  
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        var commentList = this.$("ul.comment-list");
        this.collection.each(function(comment) {
            var commentView = new CommentView({model: comment});
            commentList.append(commentView.render().el);
        });            
        return this;
    },
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="content">
   <ul class="todos-list"></ul>
</div>

// Templates
 <script type="text/template" id="todo-template">    
          <label class="todo-content"><%= content %></label>
          <ul class="comment-list" style="margin-left: 2em"></ul>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="comment-template">    
          <label class="comment-content"><%= content %></label>      
</script>
```

Todo View:

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
     tagName: "li",
     template: _.template($("#todo-template").html()),     
     events: {
         "click button.addComment": "addComment"      
     },    
     initialize: function() {
         _.bindAll(this, "render");        
         this.model.bind("change", this.render);        
         var commentsArray = this.model.get("comments");          
         var commentCollection = new CommentCollection();
         commentCollection.add(commentsArray); 
         var commentCollectionView = new CommentCollectionView({model: commentCollection});       
     }
  });
```

Comment Collection View:

```
 var CommentCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
         _.bindAll(this, "render", "appendItem", "addAll", "renderComment");
         this.model.bind("reset", this.addAll);
         this.model.bind("change", this.render);             
         this.model.bind("add", this.appendItem);            

         this.model.trigger("reset");
    },
    addAll: function() {
         this.model.each(this.appendItem);
    },        
    appendItem: function(comment) {                    
        var commentView = new CommentView({model: comment}); 
        $("ul.comment-list").append(commentView.render().el);    
   }    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the definition of the TodoModel, you did not pasted the code of it but I could assume the issue, is a common issue with data-types that are objects.

TodoModel has an attribute that you are defining in your default in this way:

```
var TodoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults : {
     //some
     comments : []
  }
});
```

So comments is an array that is always being used in all of your instances of TodoModel. Change your defaults to be in  this way:

```
var TodoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults : function(){
     return {
       //some
       comments : []
     }
  }
});
```

Update, because seems to be an issue with the scope of the selector of jQuery:
To be sure that you use only DOM elements of your current view use this. instead of the normal jQuery Call, example: this.$('ul.comment-list')

Comment: But a `ul.comment-list` selector will still select all of the lists rather than the specific list of interest.

Comment: I tried modifying that, but I didn't notice any changes. What problem exactly should this solve?

Comment: @genericatz: If you were doing this then you could end up sharing one `comments` array amongst several models, that would happen if the models started with the default `comments` and then you pushed new comments into the arrays.

Comment: To be sure that you use only DOM elements of your current view use this. instead of the normal jQuery Call, example: 
this.$('ul.comment-list')

Comment: Please incorporate your comment into your answer, because this actually helped.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is right here:

```
appendItem: function(comment) {                    
    var commentView = new CommentView({model: comment}); 
    $("ul.comment-list").append(commentView.render().el);    
}
```

Your `$('ul.comment-list')` finds all the `<ul class="comment-list">` when you only want the specific `<ul>` for that todo item.

You should break your `#todo-template` into two pieces:

```
<script type="text/template" id="todo-template">    
    <label class="todo-content"><%= content %></label>
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="comments-template">
    <ul class="comment-list" style="margin-left: 2em"></ul>
</script>
```

Then use `#comments-template` as the template for `CommentCollectionView`:

```
var CommentCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($("#comments-template").html()),
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        return this;
    },
    //...
});
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //...
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(...));

        // Use 'collection' here, not 'model'
        var c = new CommentCollectionView({collection: commentCollection});       
        this.$el.append(c.render().el);
        return this;
    }
});
```

Then your `appendItem` becomes:

```
appendItem: function(comment) {                    
    var commentView = new CommentView({model: comment}); 
    this.$el.append(commentView.render().el);
}
```

and that should put the `CommentView` into the right `<ul>`.

Comment: in your code for CommentCollectionView you mean #comments-template not #todo-template right? After modifying $(this.el) in TodoView to this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON())) I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'html' of undefined" error. Should I leave getting the comments attribute in the initialize function of TodoView? I also modified all bindings to this.collection.bind in CommentCollectionView.

Comment: @genericatz: Yes, I meant `#comments-template`. Are you using an old version of Backbone? You'd have to use `$(this.el)` instead of `this.$el` with old versions.

Comment: I updated backbone and underscore and moved getting comments to TodoViews render function because of commentsArray undefined errors. But now in TodoView render on this.$el.append(commentCollectionView.render().el);  I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined"

Comment: @genericatz: Ah, I missed the `return this` in the `render` methods. Try the updated version.

Comment: thanks, no errors. But no comments are displayed :( As I said I moved getting the comments array to the TodoView render and added to the collection var commentsArray = this.model.get("comments");
         var commentCollection = new CommentCollection();
         commentCollection.add(commentsArray);

Comment: big thanks for your excellent help though! I think it solved the problem here. I think it's something else in my code..

Comment: somehow in appendItem this.$el doesn't render the comments. I saved the reference to the DOM element in render var dom = this.$el.html(this.template());  Then I iterate through the comments collection and add comments dom.append(commentView.render().el); Not elegant, but it works!

Comment: @genericatz: Do you have the right `this`? Could you have a binding problem?

Comment: I added my render method in Edit1. I think this.$el is blocked because I iterate with over the collection with this.collection . Or any other explanation? But this works now - I hope it is not inelegant or something.