# Add items to a nested list in a template in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I have two templates:

```
<script type="text/template" id="todo-template">    
      <label class="todo-content"><%= content %></label>
      <ul class="comment-list" style="margin-left: 2em"></ul>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="comment-template">    
      <label class="comment-content"><%= content %></label>      
</script>
```

a template for a post and a template for a comment within a list of the post item. How do I add comments to the right post if there are many different posts. I can't just use

```
$("ul.comment-list").append(commentView.render().el);
```

in order to append a comment to a post, since it will add comments to all posts. How do I address the corresponding comments-list of the different todo-templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you are keeping track of your posts. If you have a view for each of your posts then in the view you can reference the right `ul` through it's `$el`,

Edit:

Looking at your code I see that each Todo has a child collection view, so what you can do is simple pass in the the right el when you instatiate the collection view,

```
var commentCollectionView =  new CommentCollectionView({collection: commentCollection, el: this.$el.find('"ul.comment-list") };
```

Then in your collection view you can just append it to its el

```
this.$el.append(commentView.render().el);
```

Comment: Actually the post is the todo, sorry. Now, I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined". I have the code here with the TodoView: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409048/iterate-through-an-array-in-a-collection-and-display-in-backbone-js . I'm a BB beginner, so it is most likely a small error but I'm getting crazy :(

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. I have a separate CommentCollectionView. Maybe I should do the stuff in the TodoView? Otherwise I can't access the TodoView right?

Comment: Well you could have a reference in your child (in your case CommentCollectionView) view to it's parent view, I'll update my answer with some example code based on the question you linked.

Comment: Also it seems like your two question are identical, you might want to add the code from your other answer into this question and delete it.